# how to validate zend form where at one field in required between two fields

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have two elements, adult no and children no, at least one field is required. How to validate this in zend framework and generate error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create Your own validator. In this case i think You could use Zend_Validate_Identical, copy its code and change isValid method to something like this:

```
public function isValid($value, $context = null)
{
    $this->_setValue((string) $value);

    if (($context !== null) && isset($context) && array_key_exists($this->getToken(), $context)) {
        $token = $context[$this->getToken()];
    } else {
        $token = $this->getToken();
    }

    if ($token === null) {
        $this->_error(self::MISSING_TOKEN);
        return false;
    }

    $strict = $this->getStrict();
    // change != to ==
    if (($strict && ($value === $token)) || (!$strict && ($value == $token)) && (&token =='' || $value == '') {
        $this->_error(self::**YOUR_ERROR _CODE**);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code is not tested but it should work :)